# How to add a new element using the jq command?

Tags: json, jq

i have this JSON data

```
{
  "slotNo": "2",
  "tracking": "797aacdf9e40443aba4c818fead0195e",
  "TEST": "ASD.mpg",
  "ZXC": "555",
  "TID": "T15789",
  "AD": "123456"
}
{
  "slotNo": "3",
  "tracking": "897aacdf9e40443aba4c818fead0195e",
  "TEST": "zxc.mpg",
  "ZXC": "666",
  "TID": "T777",
  "AD": "789456"
}
```

And I want to append `"{"List": []}` to the top of the list and save the JSON data to a file.
The result that I want is like this:

```json
{
  "List": [
    {
      "slotNo": "2",
      "tracking": "797aacdf9e40443aba4c818fead0195e",
      "TEST": "ASD.mpg",
      "ZXC": "555",
      "TID": "T15789",
      "AD": "123456"
    },
    {
      "slotNo": "3",
      "tracking": "897aacdf9e40443aba4c818fead0195e",
      "TEST": "zxc.mpg",
      "ZXC": "666",
      "TID": "T777",
      "AD": "789456"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`slurp`** option such as

```
jq -s '{ List:. }'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-7cWmnFo7hA)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Using [`inputs`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#IO) to consume the rest of the input data

```
jq '{List: [., inputs]}'
```